# SSIS Count and Summing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I wants to generates the Counts according to the P_id. Explained below with an Example.

Suppose I have total Records 500 rows which have the P_id from 1 to 100 (500 rows,Repeated P_id). In my process I filtered these P_id in 3 Products A,B,C.

Suppose

```
Product  P_ID            Rows
-------  --------------  ----
A        1 to 10         25
B                        0
C        5,6,8,55 to 75  230
```

Now I have to generate the count for A, B, C and it should be according to P_ID 
like - in C 8  10 and same in A 8 15
so total count for 8 should be 25. and I have to update those count according to the P_id.

Please Let me know If you are not getting my problem.. I will explain more.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting it. Could you show input and expected output. In the example above, if those should be rows and you simplified it for us, I think it hurts the readability of the question.

Comment: Sorry for that...but here Product A have P_id from 1 to 10 and it contains the total 25 rows( some rows repeating) but B dont have any Rows and For C have P_id - 5,6,8,55 to 75 and it total rows are 230( some rows repeating).Here I wants count as per P_id wise.Ex- P_id -1->count-1 and same way if the P_id repeats in product A and C then Sum of those P_id counts.Ex-P_ID - 8 (A - 15 & C - 10 Contains) than sum for P_id 8 count is 25.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use Count(Distinct[P_ID]). That will give you the count of the distinct P_ID values in the column.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/08/sql-server-difference-between-countdistinct-vs-countall/

Comment: Thanks Neil but I dont want the Distinct values over here, i want the Sum of the P_id according to Product wise..

Comment: Can you not just do a SUM(P_id) and group by product? I guess I am really confused as to what you are asking. Can you provide what you are expecting the result set to be?